# DQL- How to Use "&" Operator

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm using symfony4 with querybuilder.

I need to convert sql query to querybuilder

```
SELECT channelTypes FROM `camp` WHERE (total & 16) = 16
```

I have test :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$expr = $qb->expr();
$qb->where($expr->eq(('c.total & 1'), 1));
```

But I have this error :

```
Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '&'","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in bitwise `AND` operator

```
$qb->where('BIT_AND(c.total, 1) = 1')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!  work very well :)